# Not able to access array even though it is declared outside while loop in perl

Tags: arrays, perl, csv

I'm trying to read a CVS file to fetch 2nd and 3rd column in it. I have declared empty array `@x_ax` and `@dat` outside the while loop. I'm using `@x_ax` to store 2nd column and `@dat` to store 3rd column of CSV file.
Contents of `@x_ax` and `@dat` is getting printed inside while loop only but not outside.

below is my code and output.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

my @arr=();
my @x_ax=();
my @dat=();
open(FH,"new1.csv") || die "Not able to open new1.csv file $!\n";

while( my $line=<FH>)
{
        if ($line =~ m/Time/)
        {
                exit 0;
        }
        else
        {
                @arr=split(/,/,$line);
                #print "@arr[1]\n";
                push(@x_ax,$arr[1]);
                print "@x_ax \n";
                push(@dat,$arr[2]);
        }
}

print @x_ax;
print "$#x_ax and $#dat \n";

[root@localhost perl_practice]# perl test.pl 
AX_1 
AX_1 SAL 
AX_1 SAL BAS 
AX_1 SAL BAS OPT 
AX_1 SAL BAS OPT LES 
AX_1 SAL BAS OPT LES MSS
```

below is my CSV file contents

```
17:00:01,AX_1,0,0,0,0,0
17:00:01,SAL,0,0,0,0,0
17:00:01,BAS,0,0,0,0,0
16:55:02,OPT,0,0,0,0,0
17:00:01,LES,0,0,0,0,0
16:55:02,MSS,0,0,0,0,0
Time,info,dat1,dat2,dat3,dat4,dat5
```

How to access `@x_ax` and `@dat` outside while loop?.

Answer (score 3):

It's not that you can't access them outside the array, the problem is that your program never reaches those last print statements. As you have:

```
if ($line =~ m/Time/)
{
    exit 0;
}
```

And the last line of your CSV has `Time`, the program exits before reaching the final print.

If you meant the if statement to stop the loop only, you can use `last`. Then the `else` itself is not needed as well, becoming a more common loop idiom:

```
while( my $line=<FH>)
{
    last if ($line =~ m/Time/);

    @arr = split(/,/,$line);
    #print "@arr[1]\n";
    push(@x_ax,$arr[1]);
    print "@x_ax \n";
    push(@dat,$arr[2]);
}
```